# Крестики-нолике.Есть работающий код только вот я не понимаю как добавить ограничения на 2 попытки ну и результат(типо победил игрок или бот)

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import tkinter.messagebox
root = Tk()
root.title('Criss-cross')
game_run = True
field = []
cross_count = 0
def logik():
    if len(field) == 9:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Конец игры", "  Ничья!!!  ")
def click(row, col):
    if game_run and field[row][col]['text'] == ' ':
        field[row][col]['text'] = 'X'
        global cross_count
        cross_count += 1
        check_win('X')
        if game_run and cross_count < 5:
            computer_move()
            check_win('O')
def check_win(smb):
    for n in range(3):
        check_line(field[n][0], field[n][1], field[n][2], smb)
        check_line(field[0][n], field[1][n], field[2][n], smb)
    check_line(field[0][0], field[1][1], field[2][2], smb)
    check_line(field[2][0], field[1][1], field[0][2], smb)

def check_line(a1,a2,a3,smb):
    if a1['text'] == smb and a2['text'] == smb and a3['text'] == smb:
        a1['background'] = a2['background'] = a3['background'] = 'pink'
        global game_run
        game_run = False
def can_win(a1,a2,a3,smb):
    res = False
    if a1['text'] == smb and a2['text'] == smb and a3['text'] == ' ':
        a3['text'] = 'O'
        res = True
    if a1['text'] == smb and a2['text'] == ' ' and a3['text'] == smb:
        a2['text'] = 'O'
        res = True
    if a1['text'] == ' ' and a2['text'] == smb and a3['text'] == smb:
        a1['text'] = 'O'
        res = True
    return res

def computer_move():
    for n in range(3):
        if can_win(field[n][0], field[n][1], field[n][2], 'O'):
            return
        if can_win(field[0][n], field[1][n], field[2][n], 'O'):
            return
    if can_win(field[0][0], field[1][1], field[2][2], 'O'):
        return
    if can_win(field[2][0], field[1][1], field[0][2], 'O'):
        return
    for n in range(3):
        if can_win(field[n][0], field[n][1], field[n][2], 'X'):
            return
        if can_win(field[0][n], field[1][n], field[2][n], 'X'):
            return
    if can_win(field[0][0], field[1][1], field[2][2], 'X'):
        return
    if can_win(field[2][0], field[1][1], field[0][2], 'X'):
        return
    while True:
        row = random.randint(0, 2)
        col = random.randint(0, 2)
        if field[row][col]['text'] == ' ':
            field[row][col]['text'] = 'O'
            break
for row in range(3):
    line = []
    for col in range(3):
        button = Button(root, text=' ', width=4, height=2,
                        font=('Verdana', 20, 'bold'),
                        background='lavender',
                        command=lambda row=row, col=col: click(row,col))
        button.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='nsew')
        line.append(button)
    field.append(line)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Код работающий, какое конкретное затруднение у вас по решению следующих задач?

Comment: я незнаю как сделать ограничения.ну типо бот выиграл два раз подряд и чтобы писало победил игрок или бот

Comment: и буду рад если вы поможете мне

Comment: и извиняюсь что не сразу ответил.У меня свет не было